# Solve $A(t)=\int x(t)\frac{\dot{y}(t)}{y(t)}\,dt$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to solve $$A(t)=\int_t x(t)\frac{\dot{y}(t)}{y(t)}\,dt$$

where $x$ and $y$ are both functions of time, and $\dot{y}(t)/{y(t)}$ denotes the growth rate of $y$ over time. I also know that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are not independent: they are related through a single, unique relationship in which a third variable $z(t)$ appears:

$$x(t)=\frac{y(t)}{y(t)+z(t)}\quad \iff \quad y(t)=\frac{z(t)\cdot x(t)}{1-x(t)}$$

I do not know what the functions $x(t)$, $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are.

**Question:** Solve the integral $A(t)$

I'm going around in circles; no matter what I do (substitution or integration by parts), there's always an integral I can't solve. Is this to be expected???

Comment: Looks hopeless without knowing $y$ and $z$.

Comment: What do you mean by solve? Do you mean that you need to express it in closed form using only one of the three functions? Or do you mean that you need to express it purely as function of t? Further the integration boundary does not make sense as written. Do you mean integral between 0 and t?

Comment: Yes I mean the integral from zero to $t$, and I guess I have to find the antiderivative of the expression in the integral. In other words I want to find the analytic expression or closed form (or whatever it's called); I just want to arrive at an expression $A(t)=...$ which does not contain any integral. Does it make sense?

Comment: @frencho Do you have any indication that such a closed form can be achieved?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 No I don't know if such closed form can be achieved. I don't know how I would go about finding out whether there is a closed form or not. But I suspect one can integrate by parts or do some substitutions, or any other operation in order to get rid on the integral sign that's bothering me.

Comment: @frencho I'm less confident that something can be done here. If you have $z'(t) \equiv 0$ or $z'(t) = z(t)$, then you can substitute the expression for $y(t)$ and integrate. Other than that, I don't think you'll find a way without knowing some additional information about one of these three functions.

Comment: This is unsolvable without more information. If $z$ can be anything then for an arbitrary function $g$ we could have $z = -y + \frac{\dot{y}}{g}$ for which the integral would become $A(t) = \int g(t){\rm d}t$ - a general integral of an arbitrary function.